# Stripe get the zip/postcode entered

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe PaymentIntents and need to get the zip/postcode entered when using handleCardPayment() anyone know of a way to get this info so I can save just the postcode?

```
cardButton.addEventListener('click', function (ev) {
ev.preventDefault();
stripe.handleCardPayment(
    clientSecret, cardElement, {
        source_data: {
            owner: {
                name: cardholderName.value,
                address: {
                    line1: cardholderAddress,
                    line2: cardholderAddress2,
                    city: cardholderTown,
                    county: cardholderCounty
                },
                email: cardholderEmail,
                phone: cardholderTel
            }
        }
    }
).then(function (result) {
    if (result.error) {
        // Display error.message in your UI.
        //alert("NO!!!!!!!!!!")
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('payment-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
        // The payment has succeeded. Display a success message.

        var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');

        // Submit the form
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

Comment: Hmm, that's an interesting question. The postal code is available in the Source that was used to complete the payment — `result.paymentIntent.source` is the ID of that Source. You can certainly get this information server-side with https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/retrieve + https://stripe.com/docs/api/sources/object#source_object-owner-address-postal_code but I don't know if you can get it client-side.

Comment: @karllekko OK, well I can just retrieve the source server side once the form is posted if there isn't a way client-side, so that's help me anyway thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Incase anyone else needs this i've acheived it using karllekko's suggestion on the server side as below:

**CLIENT SIDE**

```
stripe.handleCardPayment(
    clientSecret, cardElement, {
        source_data: {
            owner: {
                name: cardholderName.value,
                address: {
                    line1: cardholderAddress,
                    line2: cardholderAddress2,
                    city: cardholderTown,
                    county: cardholderCounty
                },
                email: cardholderEmail,
                phone: cardholderTel
            }
        }
    }
).then(function (result) {
    if (result.error) {
        // Display error.message in your UI.
        var errorElement = document.getElementById('payment-errors');
        errorElement.textContent = result.error.message;
    } else {
        // The payment has succeeded. Display a success message.

        var form = document.getElementById('payment-form');

        var hiddenInput = document.createElement('input');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('type', 'hidden');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('name', 'srcId');
        hiddenInput.setAttribute('value', result.paymentIntent.source);
        form.appendChild(hiddenInput);

        // Submit the form
        form.submit();
    }
});
```

**SERVER SIDE**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult BookingPaymentForm(FormCollection formData, PaymentEventModel model)
{
    model.SourceId = formData["srcId"];
    var service = new SourceService();
    var source = service.Get(model.SourceId);
    var postcode = source.Owner.Address.PostalCode;
}
```

Comment: It's worth pointing out that if  `handleCardPayment` leads to an asynchronous payment flow(like the user has to complete a 3D Secure prompt), there's a chance the customer will complete payment and close their browser before the promise resolves and you have an opportunity to post your form. For that reason it's important you also [monitor payments using webhooks](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/payment-intents/verifying-status#webhooks). You can get all the payment information(like postal code) on the backend in the same way, from a webhook handler.